# Last month Same period

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I'm struggling to get the same period of last month sum. I want to compare the current month period, for instance, i have data complete June, July and 1-10 Aug 2022 so I want to get the sales from last month 1st to July 10th.

[Result required as per image paste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjIhX.png)

Comment: Can you add your input data sample?

Comment: There are no any easy solution for you. The reason is that if you want to compare 1-30 Aug, what it will mean - the hole month or exactly 30 days? In July it's a 31 days in month and in February 28/29. If still want it, you can create a set of days by Generate() and use Treatas() in Calculate() or you can play with other technics.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing with the same issue, but then I found the link solution worked for me.

[Dax Same period last months](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Dax-Same-period-last-months/m-p/837432)

Hope it helps!
Cheers